# Debian/Apache2 doen't start and stays in inactive mode

Tags: apache, debian

VPS, Debian

After purging and reinstalling Apache2 through apt-get install apache2, it does not start. After starting *service apache2 start*, it does not give any message. *systemctl status apache2* gives the following:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Su 2016-10-16 23:24:07 KRAT; 14min ago
  Process: 1953 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1947 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

there is nothing hanging on port 80. simple http-servers (by Python eg) work ok.
there is nothing in log - all files are empty.

How to make apache work?

Comment: Please post your /var/log/syslog, /var/log/apache2/error.log, /var/log/apache2/access.log while starting apache service.

Comment: @Koo, you might not have syslog output enabled since you have systemd, so also try looking at the output of `journalctl -u apache2.service`.

Comment: /var/log/syslog:
Oct 17 00:24:46 host6 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Oct 17 00:24:46 host6 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.

error.log and access.log are empty, 0 bytes

Comment: journalctl -u apache2.service:  окт 17 00:24:46 host6.olc.su systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
окт 17 00:24:46 host6.olc.su systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server

Answer (score 5):

I've found the answer. thanx for your attention. For that here is what i did for solving this.

What I have done

1. I've found that I do not have */usr/sbin/apache2* AT ALL. Have no idea, how it's happend. *sudo apachectl configtest* told me about it.
2. Took */usr/sbin/apache2* from backup. surely I could reinstall it from apt-get.
3. After that, doing *sudo apachectl configtest*, I've found a message like that:

```
    apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
    Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load: 
    Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: 
    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Action 'configtest' failed.
```

4. it was cured by *sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2-bin*

that's all. thank you

Answer (score -2):

**Solved:**

1. $ sudo apt-get update
2. $ sudo apt-get install apache2

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04